# How do I specify the type of an object returned by an inherited method in PHPDoc?

Tags: php, inheritance, containers, phpdoc

Let's say I have this abstract database table class:

```
abstract class DbTable {
    /**
     * Table records
     * @var DatabaseRecordIF[] 
     */
   protected $records;

   /**
    * Returns the records.
    * @return DatabaseRecordIf[]
    */
   public function getRecords() {
       return $this->records;
   }
}
```

I have a specific database table class to store the records from the table:

```
class MyTable extends DbTable { }
```

And I have a class that defines a record in that table:

```
class MyTableRecord implements DatabaseRecordIf { }
```

I want to tell phpDocumentor that `MyTable::getRecords()` returns `MyTableRecord[]`, not merely `DatabaseRecordIf[]`.  Is this possible?

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: `@var` is used for arguments passed to the method, `@return` for the returned datatype

Answer (score 3):

phpDocumentor defines `static` and `self` for specify the type returned by an inherited method.

> `self` An object of the class where this type was used, if inherited it will still represent the class where it was originally defined.
>
> `static`
> An object of the class where this value was consumed, if inherited it will represent the child class. (see late static binding in the PHP manual).

So *static* is the type you need for return the child type instead the parent type.

```
   /**
    * Returns the records.
    * @return static[]
    */
   public function getRecords() {
       return $this->records;
   }
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure this is a case of late binding. I have getRecords() defined in the parent class (DbTable).  There's no way for the subclass MyTable to know that its inherited getRecords is going to end up returning MyTableRecord objects.